# regarding residual storing in bootstrap regression in R

Tags: r, regression, simulation

I am trying to do bootstrapping regression by re-sampling X and Y from original sample.
I followed  a more manual approach (without using any package)
This is my work so far ,

```
set.seed(326581)
X1=rnorm(10,0,1)
Y1=rnorm(10,0,2)
data=data.frame(X1,Y1)

lst <- replicate(
  100,
  df.smpl <- data %>% sample_n(10, replace = T),
  simplify = FALSE)
```

The  list contained 100 samples where each sample has 2 columns (X,Y) with a sample size of 10 . These are the bootstrap samples.

to get bootstrap residuals , i separated the X and Y columns into two seperate data frames as follows,

```
new1=data.frame(lapply(lst, `[`, 'X1'))

new2=data.frame(lapply(lst, `[`, 'Y1))
```

After that i tried to store the residuals that got from each model fitted by using the following code,

```
res=c()
for(i in 1:100)
{
 res[i]=residuals(lm(new2[,i]~new1[,i]))
}
```

But seems like something is wrong. Can anyone help me to figure that out ?

By the way is there any easier approach than this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this unnecessarily complicated. The whole advantage of storing objects in a `list` is that you can easily loop through them with e.g. `lapply` or `sapply`.

So for example, to store the residuals of a linear model fit you can do

```
res <- lapply(lst, function(df) residuals(lm(Y1 ~ X1, data = df)))
```

This fits a linear model of the form `lm(Y1 ~ X1)` to all `data.frame`s in `lst`, and stores the residuals in a `list` of 100 vectors

```
length(res)
#[1] 100
```

You could also store residuals based on an `lm` fit to all 100 sampled `data.frame`s in a `10x100` `matrix` by using `sapply` instead of `lapply`

```
res <- sapply(lst, function(df)
    residuals(lm(Y1 ~ X1, data = df))) 
dim(res)
#[1]  10 100
```

---

### Update

In response to your comment you can do the following

First calculate and store residuals and residual-derived weights in every `data.frame` in the `list`.

```
# Add residuals and weights to lst
lst <- lapply(lst, function(df) {
    df$res <- residuals(lm(Y1 ~ X1, data = df));
    df$weights <- 1 / fitted(lm(abs(res) ~ X1, data = df))^2;
    df;
})
```

Then run a weighted linear regression and return the second (slop) coefficients

```
# Return 2nd coeffficient of weighted regression
coeff <- lapply(lst, function(df)
    coefficients(lm(Y1 ~ X1, data = df , weights = weights))[2])
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have learnt more about this apply functions

Comment: No worries @Statlover and you're very welcome. Based on my own R learning experience, familiarising yourself with the `*apply` family will definitely be time well spent and I can guarantee that it will come in handy further down the track.

Comment: You might also want to look into the `purrr` library (also in the tidyverse with `dplyr`). It has functions like `map()` which do many of the same things as the `apply()` functions but generally are better about preserving types and using friendly names. Intro: https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have a follow up question . i tried to do the weighted least squares regression using the residuals . This is my code . `weght=lapply(lst, function(data1) 1/fitted(lm(abs(res)~X,data=data1))^2)
coeff=lapply(lst, function(data1) coefficients(lm(Y ~ X, data = data1 , weights = weght))[2])` . But it giving me some errors. Can you help me to resolve it ?

Comment: @Statlover I've updated my answer; please take a look.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thank you very much for your reply . But i am getting this error ` **"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, res, value = c(`1` = -0.484104112590024,  : 
  replacement has 10 rows, data has 54 `" **. I dont know why is that

Comment: @Statlover Hmm. The example code in my update runs without errors. So the issue must be elsewhere. Can you edit your question to include the exact code you're using after the `replicate(...)` bit? Please include in your original post rather than in comments which are transient.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Never mind i found what went wrong. Thank you very much for your help.